# MySQL subquery based on other row

Tags: mysql, subquery, elgg

I have a table that looks like this:

```
entity_guid    | name           | value
---------------|----------------|--------
189501         | context        | groups
189501         | column         | 3
189509         | context        | profile
189509         | column         | 3
189521         | context        | profile
189521         | column         | 2
189551         | context        | groups
189551         | column         | 1
189552         | context        | groups
189552         | column         | 3
189554         | context        | groups
189554         | column         | 2
189559         | context        | profile
189559         | column         | 1
189591         | context        | profile
189591         | column         | 3
```

I want to update the rows where `name = column` and `value = 3` so that `value = 2`. But I only want to update the rows where another row exists with the same `entity_guid` and with `name = context` and `value = groups`.

So for example, if I were to select the rows I want to change, they would be:

```
entity_guid    | name           | value
---------------|----------------|--------
189501         | column         | 3
189552         | column         | 3
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `elggprivate_settings` WHERE `name` = 'context' AND `value` = 'groups'
) AS subquery
WHERE `name` = 'column' AND `value` = 3
```

But that of course does not work because the table is not set up like that; there are multiple rows for the same `entity_guid`. By the way, this is a table in a database for elgg, the social network engine. I am not very good with MySQL and could not find an answer online.

Comment: wouldnt you also need 189509 - column - 3?

Comment: No because 189509 has a context of profile. I need the ones where context is groups and column is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xQbert was close, but he forgot the context/groups clause for checking the subrecord existence.

```
UPDATE 
  elggprivate_settings
SET
   value = '2'
WHERE
   name = 'column' AND value = '3'
   AND entity_guid IN (
     SELECT 
       entity_guid 
     FROM 
       elggprivate_settings 
     WHERE 
       name = 'context'  
       AND value = 'groups')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would be by joining the table to itself (joins are usually faster than subqueries):

```
UPDATE elggprivate_settings es
 JOIN elggprivate_settings es2
   ON es2.entity_guid = es.entity_guid
SET es.value = '2'
WHERE es.value = '3'
AND es.name = 'column'
AND es2.name = 'context'
and es2.value = 'groups';
```